# List to Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, type-conversion

Python newbie here. I have a list of arrays of size 9. Each element of the list contains a numpy array of size (1,7). How do I convert the list into a numpy array of size (9,7)?

Thanks!

Comment: `np.squeeze(np.array(your_list))`

Comment: Please *always* provide a [mcve]. Don't just describe what you have, provide code that produces the example data. That being said, good job with your description, it was very thorough.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MechanicPig: Throwing `numpy.squeeze` at problems is a bad idea. One day, a dimension you *want* to keep suddenly has length 1, because you happened to call a function with only one data point or something, and suddenly your code crashes, or worse, silently broadcasts wrong and produces wrong results with no indication anything happened.

Comment: Does `np.vstack` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How to put a list of horizontal vectors into one array

```py
np.array(a).reshape(len(a), a[0].shape[1])
np.vstack(a)
np.r_[(*a,)]
```

`np.array(a).squeeze()` is applicable only if you know that [all meaningful dimensions have more than 1 elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72269639/list-to-numpy-array#comment127680350_72269639), so you don't accidentally drop them.

As for the speed, it may seem that `squeeze` or `reshape` is better than others, but it's seems to be true only on small arrays, e.g. arrays of size `100 x 100`:

[image: 100x100]

At large sizes, the speed of work becomes comparable, e.g. `1000 x 1000`:

[image]

Given large enough sizes, `reshape` and `vstack` are comparable and perform better than others, e.g. `10 000 x 10 000`:

[image]

As far as `np.array(...).reshape(...)` has shown equally good results at different sizes, it seems like a good choice. Although I would prefer `vstack` as a more clear and reasonably performant option.

---

p.s. Of course, performance depends on the hardware and may vary. I want to show that there is no silver bullet in this case.